# Grouped product with fixed amount of single products

Tags: grouped-products

We have **single products** in our magento.

Black Product, White Product and Grey Product.

We need to create a **"grouped product"** composed by 9 (or 16, or 32, but a fixed number) of this simple products.

The user have to select the number of **simple ones**: i.e:

x Black, y White, z Grey

The problem we have is that x+y+z = 9. (not more, not less)

Did someone knows some way to do it. (module, or whatever is needed)